# How to use and integrate the tflite model in Android Studio Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, machine-learning, image-recognition, tflite

I'm new to programming, especially in image recognition. Currently, I'm trying to create a customized image recognition system and I'm hoping you can help me :>

I've provided the code below which I found on YouTube, and I made some modifications to suit my project's needs. The code is already working since it is able to create both the h5 and tflite files.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
import json
import tensorflow as tf


# initializing part
path = r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\OCR\datasets'
testRatio = 0.2
validRatio = 0.2
imgDim = (32, 32, 3)
batchSizeVal = 40
epochsVal = 10
epochSteps = 1000

# storage
images = []
classNum = []

# setting up path, classQty refers to the number of folder in Dataset
dataList = os.listdir(path)
classQty = len(dataList)

# traversing the Dataset folder at x and the content of the folder in y
# with that we are going to resize the image to standards and add it in our list
# also we will store our classNum index to know what folder does the img came from
for x in range(0, classQty):
    picList = os.listdir(path + '/' + str(x))
    for y in picList:
        currImg = cv.imread(path + '/' + str(x) + '/' + y)
        currImg = cv.resize(currImg, (imgDim[0], imgDim[1]))
        images.append(currImg)
        classNum.append(x)
    print(x, end=' ')

# converting images into array so that we can pass it to our model
images = np.array(images)
classNum = np.array(classNum)

# Splitting Data
# create set  of training, testing, and validation
# from the original data, training set=80%, testing=25%, validation=25%
X_Train, X_Test, Y_Train, Y_Test = train_test_split(images, classNum, test_size=testRatio)
X_Train, X_Validation, Y_Train, Y_Validation = train_test_split(images, classNum, test_size=testRatio)


# storage of qty of every folder
sampleQty = []

# traversing Dataset folder to know how many img in each folder does the Dataset have.
for x in range(0, classQty):
    sampleQty.append(len(np.where(Y_Train == x)[0]))

print(sampleQty)

# creating graph to know the status of img in every folder
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.bar(range(0, classQty), sampleQty)
plt.title("No of Images for each class")
plt.xlabel("Class ID")
plt.ylabel("Number of Images")
plt.show()


# pre-processing the images
def preprocessing(img):
    img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv.equalizeHist(img)
    img = img / 255
    return img


# img = preProcessing(X_Train[1])
# img = cv.resize(img, (300, 300))
# cv.imshow('Preprocessed', img)
# cv.waitKey(0)

# Setting up img to have a grayscale value in pre-processing
X_Train = np.array(list(map(preprocessing, X_Train)))
X_Test = np.array(list(map(preprocessing, X_Test)))
X_Validation = np.array(list(map(preprocessing, X_Validation)))

# reshaping images
X_Train = X_Train.reshape(X_Train.shape[0], X_Train.shape[1], X_Train.shape[2], 1)
X_Test = X_Test.reshape(X_Test.shape[0], X_Test.shape[1], X_Test.shape[2], 1)
X_Validation = X_Validation.reshape(X_Validation.shape[0], X_Validation.shape[1], X_Validation.shape[2], 1)

# augmenting images (adding zoom, shift, and rotation)
dataGen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1,
                             height_shift_range=0.1,
                             zoom_range=0.05,
                             shear_range=0.1,
                             rotation_range=5)
# this means that we are going to generate along with the training not before the training.
dataGen.fit(X_Train)

# one hot encoding the matrices
Y_Train = to_categorical(Y_Train, classQty)
Y_Test = to_categorical(Y_Test, classQty)
Y_Validation = to_categorical(Y_Validation, classQty)


# creating LeNet model of CNN
def mymodel():
    filter_qty = 60
    filter1_size = (5, 5)
    filter2_size = (3, 3)
    pool_s = (2, 2)
    nodes_qty = 500

    model = Sequential()
    model.add((Conv2D(filter_qty, filter1_size, input_shape=(imgDim[0], imgDim[1], 1), activation='relu')))
    model.add((Conv2D(filter_qty, filter1_size, activation='relu')))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=pool_s))
    model.add((Conv2D(filter_qty // 2, filter2_size, activation='relu')))
    model.add((Conv2D(filter_qty // 2, filter2_size, activation='relu')))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=pool_s))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(nodes_qty, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(classQty, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics='accuracy')

    return model


# calling the method for creating model
modell = mymodel()

print(modell.summary())

# training
# requesting data to dataGen in batches


history = modell.fit_generator(dataGen.flow(X_Train, Y_Train, batch_size=batchSizeVal),
                               steps_per_epoch=epochSteps, epochs=epochsVal,
                               validation_data=(X_Validation, Y_Validation),
                               shuffle=1)

# plotting
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.legend(['training', 'validation'])
plt.title('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.legend(['training', 'validation'])
plt.title('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.show()
score = modell.evaluate(X_Test, Y_Test, verbose=0)

print('Test Score : {0} \nTest Accuracy: {1}'.format(score[0], score[1]))

# saving the model
modelDict = modell.to_json()

with open("data.json", "w") as trained_data:
    json.dump(modelDict, trained_data)

modell.save_weights('data_weights.h5')
modell.save('data_model.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tf.keras.models.load_model('data_model.h5'))
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("neuralNetModel.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

In this section, I'm showing the code where I test the model I created. It generates an output that displays the class index that the image belongs to. The class index is composed of numbers 0-27 that correspond to the Filipino alphabet. Please note that the letter "a" corresponds to 0, and "Z" corresponds to 27. The letters "ñ" and "ng" are also included. In the output, the confidence level of the model's prediction is also displayed in relation to the class index and the image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model

# width = 640
# height = 480
# Initialization part
threshold = 0.65

# Load the model from the JSON string
model = load_model('data_model.h5')
model.load_weights("data_weights.h5")


def preprocessing(img):
    img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv.equalizeHist(img)
    img = img / 255
    return img


def predict_image(img_path):
    # read the image
    imgOrig = cv.imread(img_path)

    # converting img to numpy array
    img = np.asarray(imgOrig)
    # resizing img
    img = cv.resize(img, (32, 32))

    # sending img to preprocessing
    img = preprocessing(img)

    cv.imshow("Processed Image", img)

    # reshaping img
    img = img.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)

    # predicting
    classIndex = int(model.predict_classes(img))

    predictions = model.predict(img)

    # this will return the element who have the highest value
    probVal = np.amax(predictions)
    print(classIndex, probVal)

    if probVal > threshold:
        cv.putText(imgOrig, str(classIndex) + " : " + str(probVal), (50, 50), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv.imshow('Original Img', imgOrig)
    cv.waitKey(0)  # wait until a key is pressed to close the windows

    print("Predicted class index:", classIndex)
    print("Predicted probability value:", probVal)


# example usage:
predict_image('example4.jpg')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGXDb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xctEF.png)

The first image is the output that shows the predicted class index which is 1 and is equivalent to b. The second image is the handwritten image that I tried to recognize using the model.

All in all, the presented code above shows the model that I created with the help of a Youtube video and I also have the tflite format of that model. Now, I want to integrate and use it in my Android studio Kotlin. I already integrated it by adding a New Tensor Flow Lite Model. However, I do not know how to use the model.

These are my objectives related to my project:

1. I want to feed the image from the downloads folder in the Android phone named image.jpeg. Take note that the image.jpeg contains the handwritten letter just like the example picture above. Please include the pre-processing of the image before feeding it into my model if possible.
2. I want to get the result from the model and display it on my activity.

I hope you can help me with this. I really felt cornered since I don't know how to do it.